# MATLAB: Dividing a year-length varying-resolution time vector into months

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a time series in the following format:

```
time       data value
733408.33  x1
733409.21  x2
733409.56  x3
etc..
```

The data runs from approximately 01-Jan-2008 to 31-Dec-2010.
I want to separate the data into columns of monthly length.

For example the first column (January 2008) will comprise of the corresponding data values:

`(first 01-Jan-2008 data value):(data value immediately preceding the first 01-Feb-2008 value)`

Then the second column (February 2008):

`(first 01-Feb-2008 data value):(data value immediately preceding the first 01-Mar-2008 value)`

et cetera...

Some ideas I've been thinking of but don't know how to put together:

1. Convert all serial time numbers (e.g. 733408.33) to character strings with `datestr`
2. Use `strmatch('01-January-2008',DatesInChars)` to find the indices of the rows corresponding to 01-January-2008
3. Tricky part (?): `TransformedData(:,i) = OriginalData(start:end)` ? `end = strmatch(1) - 1` and `start = 1`. Then change `start` at the end of the loop to `strmatch(1)` and then run step 2 again to find the next "starting index" and change `end` to the "new" `strmatch(1)-1` ?

Having it speed optimized would be nice; I am going to apply it on data sampled ~2 million times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) with a list a list of last days of the month as the second parameter (Note: use `histc` with the two return functions).
The edge list can easily be created with `datenum` or `datevec`.

This way you don't have operation on string and you that should be fast.

EDIT:
Example with result in a simple data structure (including some code from @Rody):

```
% Generate some test times/data

tstart = datenum('01-Jan-2008');
tend   = datenum('31-Dec-2010');

tspan = tstart : tend;
tspan = tspan(:) + randn(size(tspan(:))); % add some noise so it's non-uniform

data = randn(size(tspan));

% Generate list of edge
edge = [];
for y = 2008:2010
    for m = 1:12
        edge = [edge datenum(y, m, 1)];
    end
end

% Histogram
[number, bin] = histc(tspan, edge);

% Setup of result
result = {};

for n = 1:length(edge)
    result{n}  = [tspan(bin == n), data(bin == n)];    
end

% Test
% 04-Aug-2008 17:25:20
datestr(result{8}(4,1))
tspan(data ==  result{8}(4,2))
datestr(tspan(data ==  result{8}(4,2)))
```

Comment: +1: Yes...I always forget about `histc`. That would probably be the fastest way to go here, plus, the data/dates need not be sorted. Can you provide a complete example (you can probably copy-paste a lot from my answer)

Comment: Thanks. Works great with a small modification: it doesn't seem to form the last column (i.e. Dec 2010 to end of Dec 2010). Instead it makes a empty cell. I packaged your code into a function and added an if statement: if `last cell = empty` then fill it with the remaining data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have sorted, non-equally-spaced date numbers, the way to go here is to put the relevant data in a *cell array*, so that each entry corresponds to the next month, and can hold a different amount of elements.

Here's how to do that quite efficiently:

```
% generate some test times/data

tstart = datenum('01-Jan-2008');
tend   = datenum('31-Dec-2010');

tspan = tstart : tend;
tspan = tspan(:) + randn(size(tspan(:))); % add some noise so it's non-uniform

data = randn(size(tspan));


% find month numbers
[~,M] = datevec(tspan);

% find indices where the month changes
inds = find(diff([0; M]));

% extract data in columns
sz = numel(inds)-1;
cols = cell(sz,1);
for ii = 1:sz-1
    cols{ii} = data( inds(ii) : inds(ii+1)-1 );
end
```

Note that it can be difficult to determine which entry in `cols` belongs to which month, year, so here's how to do it in a more human-readable way:

```
% change this line: 
[y,M] = datevec(tspan);

% and change these lines: 
cols = cell(sz,3);
for ii = 1:sz-1
    cols{ii,1} = data( inds(ii) : inds(ii+1)-1 );

    % also store the year and month 
    cols{ii,2} = y(inds(ii)); 
    cols{ii,3} = M(inds(ii)); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a `timeVals` an Nx1 double vector holding the time value of each datum. Assuming `data` is also an Nx1 array. I also assume `data` and `timeVals` are sorted according to time: that is, the samples you have are ordered according to the time they were taken.

How about:

```
subs = @(x,i) x(:,i);
months = subs( datevec(timeVals), 2 ); % extract the month of year as a number from the time
r = find( months ~= [months(2:end), months(end)+1] );
monthOfCell = months( r );
r( 2:end ) = r( 2:end ) - r( 1:end-1 );
dataByMonth = mat2cell( data', r ); % might need to transpose data or r here...
timeByMonth = mat2cell( timeVal', r );
```

After running this code, you have a cell array `dataByMonth` each cell contains all data relevant to a specific month. The corresponding cell of `timeByMonth` holds the sampling times of the data of the respective month. Finally, `monthOfCell` tells you what is the month's number (1-12) of each cell.